# Getting parameter from URL without $_GET

Tags: php, get, mysqli

Basically trying to make a page for every single entry in my mysql and every single entry once clicked will be redirected to a page in which displays the data in depth. 
Example of Page: ....www.example.com/examplepage.php/3 the 3 being $row[0] which is the ID # of the entry

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

$article_page = "http://localhost/MCA/testpage.php/$row[0]";

echo '<tr><td><a href=' . "$article_page" .'>' . $row[1] . '</a></td><td>' .
                            $row[2] . '</td><td>' .
                            $row[3] . '</td><td>' . 
                            $row[4] .'</td><td>' . 
    date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A", strtotime($row[5])) .'</td></tr>';

     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to apply a URI redirect rule through your `.htaccess` file or otherwise.

An example of a change would be the following:

**.htaccess**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**PHP**:

```
$uri_segments = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use URL rewriting for a clean way to do this.
(See httpd mod_rewrite).